# ¿Cómo deshabilitar listado de checkboxes cuando llego a una cantidad seleccionada?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Tengo un cierto número de checkbox para seleccionar profesores para recibir clases online.

Lo que quiero hacer es recibir un key y un value a localStorage de los profesores, pero tengo que limitar la cantidad a solo 3 de ellos, es decir, solo se pueden elegir 3, y si quisieras elegir otro, deberías quitar la selección de uno u otro en el checkbox seleccionado.

Lo que pude hacer hasta el momento es limitar con JS la cantidad de checkbox que se pueden seleccionar a 3, y al querer seleccionar un 4to checkbox, genera un alert de que no se pueden seleccionar más.

```js
window.localStorage.clear()

function validation(choosen, obj) {
  limit = 3;
  cont = 0;
  if (obj.checked) {


    for (i = 0; ele = document.getElementById('choosen').getElementsByTagName('input')[i]; i++){

      if (ele.checked){
        cont++;
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
      var key = localStorage.key(i);
      document.getElementById(key).checked = true;
    }

    if (cont > limit){
      obj.checked = false;
      alert('Solo se pueden elegir 3 (tres) profesores!');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled ~ span {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

```html
<form id="choosen" method="get" name="disabling" action="">
  <div class="row" id="child">
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center tsize mt-5">
        TITULO DE LAS CLASES
      </div>
      <div class="row mt-2 d-flex justify-content-around">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="profe-01" value="nombre del profesor 1" name="disable" onchange="validation('choosen', this)" onclick="if(this.checked)localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else localStorage.removeItem(this.id);" />
          <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
            <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h5>
          </span>
          <h5 class="impact text-center name">
            TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
          </h5>
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="profe-02" value="nombre del profesor 2" name="disable" onchange="validation('choosen', this)" onclick="if(this.checked)localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else localStorage.removeItem(this.id);" />
          <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
            <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h5>
          </span>
          <h5 class="impact text-center name">
            TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
          </h5>
        </label>        

        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="profe-03" value="nombre del profesor 3" name="disable" onchange="validation('choosen', this)" onclick="if(this.checked)localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else localStorage.removeItem(this.id);" />
          <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
            <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h5>
          </span>
          <h5 class="impact text-center name">
            TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
          </h5>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="row mt-2 d-flex justify-content-around">
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="profe-04" value="nombre del profesor 4" name="disable" onchange="validation('choosen', this)" onclick="if(this.checked)localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else localStorage.removeItem(this.id);" />
          <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
            <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h5>
          </span>
          <h5 class="impact text-center name">
            TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
          </h5>
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="profe-05" value="nombre del profesor 5" name="disable" onchange="validation('choosen', this)" onclick="if(this.checked)localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else localStorage.removeItem(this.id);" />
          <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
            <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h5>
          </span>
          <h5 class="impact text-center name">
            TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
          </h5>
        </label>        

        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" id="profe-06" value="nombre del profesor 6" name="disable" onchange="validation('choosen', this)" onclick="if(this.checked)localStorage.setItem(this.id,this.value);else localStorage.removeItem(this.id);" />
          <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
            <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
              <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
            </h5>
          </span>
          <h5 class="impact text-center name">
            TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
          </h5>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

El problema es que en localStorage, ese 4to elemento, lo ingresa y me quedan 4 elementos, y no 3 como debería ser.

Lo que quiero hacer es que, una vez que selecciono 3 profesores en los checkbox, los demás queden deshabilitados. Si se quita al menos una selección y vuelven a quedar en menor que 3, se vuelvan a habilitar todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás definiendo dos acciones, *onchange* para "validar" y *onclick* para guardar en *localStorage*, saltando la validación.

Lo ideal es no agregar los eventos directamente en la etiqueta HTML y, de hecho, usar solo uno para realizar la validación y guardar en *localStorage*. La idea es que se puedan marcar los elementos y, al llegar al límite permitido, deshabilitar los que no se han marcado para que no puedan agregarse.

- Para poder procesar el formulario y se incluyan todos los seleccionados, es necesario agregar corchetes, es decir: `name="disable[]"`
- Cuando se haya cargado el DOM, obtienes todos los *checkbox* por nombre
- Recorres los elementos para asignar evento *onchange*, llamando a la función `validation`
- En la función obtienes los elementos marcados
- Recorres todos los elementos para saber qué hacer con cada uno:

  - Si está marcado o no se ha llegado al límite: Habilitar
  - Si está marcado: Agregar a seleccionados
  - Si ya se llegó al límite y no está marcado: Deshabilitar
- Al terminar el ciclo guardas los seleccionados en *localStorage*

```js
// Ejecutar hasta que se haya cargado el DOM
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // window.localStorage.clear(); // Descomenta esta línea
    
    // Máximo de profesores que se pueden seleccionar
    let max = 3;

    // Obtener todos los checkboxes por nombre
    let checks = document.querySelectorAll('[name="disable[]"]');
    // Recorrer para asignar evento cuando cambien
    checks.forEach(chk => chk.addEventListener('change', validation));

    // Validar
    function validation() {
        // Guardar profesores seleccionados en un arreglo
        let profes = [];
        // Obtener solo los que están marcados
        let checked = document.querySelectorAll(':checked');
        // Recorrer todos
        checks.forEach(chk => {
            // Si está marcado o no se ha llegado al límite
            if(chk.checked || checked.length < max) {
                // Quitar clase a etiqueta
                chk.closest('label').classList.remove('disabled');
                // Habilitar checkbox para permitir cambios
                chk.disabled = false;
                // Si está marcado, agregar a seleccionados
                if(chk.checked) {
                    profes.push(chk.id);
                }
            } else {
                // No está marcado y ya se llegó al límite
                // Agregar clase a etiqueta para saber que no se puede seleccionar
                chk.closest('label').classList.add('disabled');
                // Deshabilitar ckeckbox
                chk.disabled = true;
            }
        });
        // Guardar en localStorage
        // localStorage.setItem("profes", JSON.stringify(profes)); // Descomenta esta línea
    }
});
```

```css
label { display:block; }
h5 { display:inline-block; }
.disabled { background:#ccc; }
```

```html
<form id="choosen" method="get" name="disabling" action="">
    <div class="row" id="child">
        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center tsize mt-5">
                TITULO DE LAS CLASES
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-2 d-flex justify-content-around">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="profe-01" value="nombre del profesor 1" name="disable[]">
                    <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
                        <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="impact text-center name">
                        TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
                    </h5>
                </label>
                            
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="profe-02" value="nombre del profesor 2" name="disable[]">
                    <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
                        <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="impact text-center name">
                        TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
                    </h5>
                </label>        

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="profe-03" value="nombre del profesor 3" name="disable[]">
                    <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
                        <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="impact text-center name">
                        TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
                    </h5>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="row mt-2 d-flex justify-content-around">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="profe-04" value="nombre del profesor 4" name="disable[]">
                    <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
                        <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="impact text-center name">
                        TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
                    </h5>
                </label>
                            
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="profe-05" value="nombre del profesor 5" name="disable[]">
                    <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
                        <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="impact text-center name">
                        TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
                    </h5>
                </label>        

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="profe-06" value="nombre del profesor 6" name="disable[]">
                    <span class="btn profesor boton-size-u btn-green text-uppercase">
                        <h5 class="impact shadow text-center pt-5 name">
                            <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        </h5>
                    </span>
                    <h5 class="impact text-center name">
                        TIPO<br>Nombre del profesor
                    </h5>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Cuando necesites acceder a los profesores seleccionados:

```
let guardados = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profes"));
```

**Nota:** Para poder probar aquí, es necesario comentar las líneas que acceden a *localStorage*, quita los comentarios para hacerlo funcionar en tu proyecto:

```
// ***** Esto:
// window.localStorage.clear(); // Descomenta esta línea

// ***** Debería quedar así:
window.localStorage.clear();
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por el gran aporte. La solución es impecable.